# Dots on local, commas on server

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, numbers, prestashop

since few days, I have issues with a website i'm working on.
This website is made with Prestashop and when i test it on my local server (i'm using WAMP) all is ok, but when i upload the site on my web server, some request send prestashop to get decimals numbers return me numbers like this XX,XX (and on Wamp, i get XX.XX)

the problem is this comma cause many problems to set prices or tax

did anyone already seen this kind of issues ?

Thanks (and sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What's your locale setting locally and on the server?

Comment: How can i find them ?

Comment: Run `locale | grep NUMERIC` on the server, I've no idea for windows, possibly something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP probably uses the system default locale. Use the following to make sure you use a specific locale:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); // for Dutch
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Locale determines how date, currencies and numeric values are formatted. You can change the locale for specific PHP functions only (such as currency formatting).

Setting locale for currency only:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_EN'); // for English
```

Setting locale for numeric formatting only:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_EN'); // for English
```

See above link for more detailed information on that topic.